# Evaluate my forecast using a Pipeline Model

Tags: apache, scala, apache-spark-mllib, random-forest, databricks

There is a part of the code below ; I would like to know how can I evaluate my forecast ? 
If, I want to know the importance of my feature  is there a trick to use the **featureImportances** of [RandomForestRegressionModel](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.regression.RandomForestRegressionModel) ? Should I directly switch to a [RandomForestRegressionModel](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.regression.RandomForestRegressionModel) and not using a [PipelineModel](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel) ?

I read that using a Pipeline could give better results that's why i'm using it. 
I tried using a [RegressionEvaluator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.RegressionEvaluator@isLargerBetter:Boolean) but i don't get what I want.

Or should I just think simple and convert my DataFrame to an RDD and use the [RegressionMetrics](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.RegressionMetrics) to get the mean Squared Error.

To summarize, i just need to know what is the best method to evaluate my forecast.

```
val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(Array("customers", "year", "month", "dayOfMonth", "dayOfWeek", "weekOfYear", "dayOfYear"))
  .setOutputCol("features")

val limitDate = "2017-04-01"
val trainingData = DF_2.filter(DF_2("time").lt(lit(limitDate)))
//trainingData.printSchema()

val rf = new RandomForestRegressor()
  .setNumTrees(60) 
  .setMaxDepth(25) 
  .setMaxBins(100)
  .setLabelCol("amount")
  .setFeaturesCol("features")

val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(assembler, rf))

//Train the model
val model = pipeline.fit(trainingData)

//Make predictions
val predictions = model.transform(DF_2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who need an answer ; here how do I deal with this problem.

You can "transform"/"cast" your Pipeline Model to the type that u need using asInstanceOf like this :

```
val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(assembler, rf))
val newModel = model.stages("NumberStage").asInstanceOf[TheModelYouWant]
```

Change *NumberStage* with the index of your Algorithm in your Pipeline, in my Pipeline it was 1. (For rf)

Change *TheModelYouWant* for the type of the model you need, in my case it was RandomForestRegressionModel.

Then you can create your own [Evaluator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.package) that you want to use for your model.

If you want to transform your DF in a RDD[(Double, Double)], u can use .rdd & .map :

```
val predictionsAndLabels= df.select("amount", "prediction").rdd.map {case (row) => ((row.getInt(0).toDouble), (row.getDouble(1)))}
```

I have now a RDD[(Double, Double)] and you can use it for [RegressionMetrics](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.RegressionMetrics).
I hope it will help someone.